# Can a USB receiver be used as a USB drive?

Tags: usb, receiver

I have an old Mini receiver for an old mouse and keyboard from Logitech and I was thinking if somehow it can be used as a USB drive to store some data.

Could this be done somehow? If there is some way this would be awesome and I wont throw this piece of hardware to the trash. Btw. the model of the receiver is: **Logitech USB mini-receiver 831842-0000**

[image]

Comment: This is an off topic **usage** question not an on-topic design question.

Answer (score 3):

No. Not unless it was designed to be a flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

That mini-receiver contains a USB slave interface and a small-distance radio transceiver, probably all integrated in one chip. In theory you might be able to hack it and change its function, but that would be a very big project (think man years, maybe more than 10). So all that you could realistically re-use when you turn it into a storage device is the USB connector and the plastic housing...

Comment: So, is it possible?

Comment: There is a slight possibility, but it involves *quite a bit* of work. Possible. Practical? Not in the slightest.

Comment: @Derfder it's possible in the same way that you can turn a volkswagon beetle into a muscle car. By ripping everything out, and putting tons of new parts and work into it.

Comment: @Derfder: re-read the last sentence of my answer. Just in case the ironic tone is lost in the ascii rendition: feel free to read is as a big NOOOOOO.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen do you have any experience with customizing USB devices (receivers, memories, modems etc.) ?

Comment: No, I stick to the virtual serial port. It is enough trouble to keep that working on all kinds of platforms.